# Handling different user accounts' data in my application

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android studio. The application allows users to create their account. I am able to allow users to sign up and log into their account by using shared preference.

In this application, there is a ListView that displays tasks added by the user. However, if a new user logs into the application, the data from the previous user who is logged out, is displayed in the ListView.

How can i handle the activities of the different users?

Comment: Associate each task with the id of an user. So you can then show it to that user only. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should use database and crate a relation between users and tasks, to filter tasks added by logged user

Answer (score 0):

You need to save these data in a database and add to each task a `userId` accordingly, then when you load these items query them and retrieve only the ones corresponding to the id of the user logged in